# References Tables: all in one or separate table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a `group` table - should `option_id` or `extras_id` should be in separate tables or all in one table? See below what I meant:

**group table:**

```
mysql> select * from `group`;
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | name      | type   |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | Group One | extra  |
|  2 | Group Two | option |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

There are two of group (extra or option).

**group_extra table:**

```
mysql> select * from `group_extra`;
+----+----------+----------+
| id | group_id | extra_id |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |        1 |      123 |
|  2 |        1 |      124 |
+----+----------+----------+
```

`group_id` = 1 have a list of ref `extra_id`

**group_option table:**

```
mysql> select * from `group_option`;
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | group_id | option_id |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 |        2 |        45 |
|  2 |        2 |        46 |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

`group_id` = 2 have a list of ref `option_id`

**group_option_extra table:**

```
mysql> select * from `group_option_extra`;
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| id | group_id | option_id | extra_id |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
|  1 |        1 |         0 |      123 |
|  2 |        1 |         0 |      124 |
|  3 |        2 |        45 |        0 |
|  4 |        2 |        46 |        0 |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Or should the table look like this, combine `group_option` and `group_extra` into one? which one is recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep them separate.

You don't really need the type column - you can just check if any rows exist in the other tables to see which type it is.

Comment: How would you write that SQL Query to check  if any rows exist in the other tables? I dont have write two separate query

Comment: `SELECT id, name, EXISTS (SELECT * FROM group_extra WHERE group_id = group.id) has_extra, EXISTS (SELECT * FROM group_option WHERE group_id = group.id) has_option FROM group` Note: It's not a good idea to name the ID column id in all the tables - it will drive you nuts when you do joins. Give each id column a different name, i.e. even in the group table, still call it group_id and not id. (This only applies to columns you intent to join. Other columns can have duplicate names, you don't need to prefix every column, that too will drive you nuts.)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Ariel. Just last question... Could you think of good `group` table name? because its related option or extra food tables.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your last question.

Comment: I want to rename `group` table name to something else... Im thinking of good group table name that make sense for extras and options

Comment: You have a name column in there. What is it a name of?

Answer (score 3):

Separate.

"together" is known as the "One True Lookup Table" *anti-pattern*

See

- [sql performance of a lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373910/sql-performance-of-a-lookup-table/5374136#5374136)
- http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html