# Multiple select statements in a stored procedure sql server 2005

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, struts-1

Is it possible to add multiple select statements in a single stored procedure . The select statements are getting data from same tables. If yes, could anybody provide an example in adding multiple select statements, which retrieve data from different tables in a stored procedure.

Actually I am having list like state,city, university,college,department in my maintenance (same) table. As per the query i want execute the query and populate the value in my drop down list .

Comment: Can you post examples of the original tables and the results you are looking to get?

Answer (score 2):

This proc will return mutiple result sets to the client

```
CREATE PROC whatever
AS
SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table1
SELECT col3, col4, col5 FROM Table2
SELECT col1, col3 FROM Table3
GO
```

You can use DataAdaptor.Fill and then you can DataTable(0), DataTable(1) and DataTable(2)

Or iterate over them with [DataReader.NextResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.framework.datareader.nextresult.aspx)

If you have "all data in one table" then you have a bad design: [sql performance of a lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373910/sql-performance-of-a-lookup-table/5374136#5374136)

Comment: I want to check lots of condition is that possible...

Comment: @user964802: no idea. You need to give us more information

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but for example this would work:

```
  select id,name from table1 where code<=500
  union all
  select id,name from table2 where code >=1000 and code <=2000
```

Comment: Is it possible to make in same table it self.In my table (Maintenance) i have stored all the values like(state,city, university etc..)in one table it self.By query  i just retrieve and populate the values in my struts page . so kindly reply please ..