# Performance comparison in SQL Server when retrieving rows

Tags: sql, performance, select, comparison, inner-join

I wanted to know which is faster from the following scenario:

Three tables A, B and C - Is it more efficient to use

1. `Select * from A, select * from B` and then C and hence receive all their results
2. `Inner join A B and C` and receive all results in a single array?

Thanks and hope it is clear

Comment: How are the tables related? Do they have foreign key references to each other or are they completely unrelated?

Comment: yes they are related by foreign keys. I just want all the results from the tables. should i do so with 3 arrays or 1 array?

Comment: Do they have 1:1 relations, or 1:many?

Comment: 1 to many isnt it? is it possible to have foreign keys without 1 to many?

Comment: i thought 1 to 1 are related by primary keys... at least on access

Comment: @Shakir: they are. The PK of the "child* table is also the FK, which links to the PK of the "parent" tables, which must be the same of course...

Comment: ahhh yes i seemed to have forgotten that they also call this foreign keys. thanks teacher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 2, otherwise

1. You get 3 sets of data to process in the client
2. 3 round trips to the database server
3. More records than you need , because no filtering via the JOIN is applied in SQL Server
4. Databases are designed to JOIN
5. Don't think you can do better than the RDBMS
6. ...

Comment: yes it makes sense. i was just thinking the joining may cause a bigger load than just getting the data without "thinking".

Comment: @Seph: then you need to JOIN in the client. However, you can also retrieve 3 recordsets in a single call if you desire (with a batch or a stored procedure). Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7553896/27535

Answer (score 0):

theoretically, method 1 should be slower because you will be firing 3 sql statement if compare with method 2, only 1 single sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

The join should be faster since indexes, if any, will be used whenever possible; however, don't ever use 'select *' instead list only the columns you need. Using * will cause performance degradation just by the fact that you'll be retrieving more columns than needed or if the table structure changes and more columns are added, for example blobs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.
I once read from 3 Tables using joins, which generated me about 1 Million rows in the result set to read. Now I'm using 3 simple selects, wich gives me about 44000 rows overall, and join them in memory using .net Dictionaries (It's a C# application). Obviously this is much faster than retreiving a million rows via network.