# Moving lookup / reference tables to a new schema

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, database-design, ef-code-first

We are building ASP.NET MVC3 web applications using Visual Studio, SQL Server 2008 R2 & EF Code First 4.1.

Quite often we have smaller, what we call, "lookup" tables. For example a "Status" table contain an "Id" and a "Name". As the application grows these tables become quite frequent and I would like to know the best way to "group" these lesser important tables away from the crux of the application.

It has been suggest to me to add a prefix like "LkStatus" to help me but what about moving all the lookup tables out of dbo and into there own schema?

Can anyone see any drawbacks in this method?

Thanks Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No drawbacks with this method. I'm a fan of schemas personally. I'd use `Lookup` though

To change your table schema, you have two ways:

```
ALTER SCHEMA Lookup TRANSFER dbo.SomeTable
```

or

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON dbo.SomeTable TO Lookup
```

Comment: +1, ALTER SCHEMA... TRANSFER was new to me.  Cool and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be down to preference.  There really isn't a "gotcha" either way.  I prefer a table prefix but wouldn't be bothered either way.  We use LU_*.  As long as either option is enforced that maintenance down the line will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Since the tables are small, what about grouping them together into a single table? Instead of using the table name as a pseudo-key, use a real key. For example, you could have a table called Lookup, with an Id, Type, Name and Value, where Type = 'Status' for your status values. Seting the clustered index to (Type, Name) would physically group all rows of the same type together, which would make it fast to read them all as a group, if needed.

If your Names can have different data types, add an extra column for each required type: one for integers, one for strings, one for floats, etc. You can do something similar using an XML column; the T-SQL takes just a little more effort.

Comment: Example of why this is a bad idea: how do you ensure that you don't have Status = 'Pink' because you now have colours mixed with status. This is known as the "One True Lookup Table" anti-pattern. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5374136/27535

Comment: Thanks for the input RickNZ, I thought it was a great idea too until I read gbn's links and also this: http://www.projectdmx.com/dbdesign/lookup.aspx

Comment: It depends on how you're using the tables. If they are just for "lookups," and aren't referenced as FKs, then the approach I suggest is more appropriate than if you do use them as FKs. For lookups, your code has to either choose a table name or the value of a Type-like column; it's really the same thing. If you have a separate table of Status values, there's still nothing to prevent you from setting one of them to 'Pink'.